# Admin Routes (or Prefix Routes) in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I create admin specific routes in Laravel 4 (Restfull Controllers):

```
/admin/users        (get - /admin/users/index)
/admin/users/create (get)
/admin/users/store  (post)
```

I want to know:

- What Files and where I need create theam
- How I need create the route

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Laravel 4` you can now use `prefix`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@home');

    Route::get('posts', 'AdminController@showPosts');

    Route::get('another', function() {
        return 'Another routing';
    });

    Route::get('foo', function() {
        return Response::make('BARRRRR', 200);
    });

    Route::get('bazz', function() {
        return View::make('bazztemplate');
    });

});
```

Comment: But you must do `composer dump-autoload` after updating controller directory. :)

Answer (score 5):

For your subfolders, as I answer here ["route-to-controller-in-subfolder-not-working-in-laravel-4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504082/route-to-controller-in-subfolder-not-working-in-laravel-4/14519555#14519555), seems to have no "friendly" solution in this laravel 4 beta.

@Aran, if you make it working fine, please add an code sample of your controller, route, and composer.json files :

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'admin.Users');
```

or

```
Route::resource('admin', 'admin.Users');
```

thanks

Comment: Right, but: where I need create files? What name? controller/admin/UsersController.php? class UsersController extends... ?

Comment: I see you answer for other question ("route-to-controller-in-subfolder-not-working-in-laravel-4"), and works (but, now I'm sure about Laravel 4 is 100% more hard than 3). Thanks

Comment: beta is harder, wait for stable release :)

Answer (score 3):

Really useful tool that you can use is the `artisan` CLI.

Using this you'll be able to generate the needed function file with all the required routes for it to become RESTful.

```
php artisan controller:make users
```

Would generate the function file for you. Then in your routes.php file you can simply add

```
Route::resource('users', 'Users');
```

This'll setup all the necessary routes.

For more information on this you should read the documentation at.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#resource-controllers

http://four.laravel.com/docs/artisan

**Edit:**

To make this admin specific, simple alter the code like follows and move the controller to a admin folder inside the controllers folder.

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'admin.Users');
```

The first paramater is the route, the second is the controller filename/folder.

In Laravel if you placed a controller inside a folder, to specific it in a route or URL you'd use the a dot for folders.

You can then expand on this and add Authentication using Route Filters and specifically the code found "Pattern Based Filters" found on the page below.

http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Comment: But, my question is exacly you ask for me read 'for more information', in the other words, I know about php artisan controller and resouce, but I don't know about admin routes (nested controllers), and admin routes with Restfull Controllers.

Comment: Ah ok, I read the question and didn't realise you specifically wanted a admin routing. I'll edit my answer to include.

Comment: I want to know, how create inner file you know? I need see the code in Controller, the code in Route and location in folders. Because I try a lot and not have success.

Comment: I've altered my answer to include a different route and also explained briefly the use of dots for folders in routes/urls. Also mentioned about Route Filters for protected this with authentication.

Comment: One more little question: if I want create customize method (not create, store), for example: lastPosts, with get requisition: get_lastPosts( ) works?

Comment: Laravel 4 now follows the PHP Fig standards which means camelCase methods e.g. ```getLastPosts($id)```, but any additional methods you'll have to manually add the Routes in the routes.php file. ```Route::get('admin/users/{id}/last-posts', 'admin.Users@getLastPosts')```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23161/discussion-between-patrick-maciel-and-aran)

Comment: Doesn't work. I test and Laravel say: 'admin.Projects' doesn't exists, or, 'admin.ProjectsController' doesn't exists

Comment: Have you updated your autoloader using ```composer update```?

Comment: no, why I need do that? (sorry for the question, I don't know, really).

Comment: All classes and files are registered in the Autoloader, and Laravel uses composer's generated Autoloader. To get classes registered to the Autoloader you need to run ```composer update```.

Comment: Just comment: using your solution, doesn't work. Solution of Pierre Broucz, works great (in other question: route-to-controller-in-subfolder-not-working-in-laravel-4).

Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel 4 - Add Admin Controller Easily

This was driving me insane for ages, but i worked it out.

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('admin', 'Admin_HomeController@showIndex');
```

**/controllers/Admin/HomeController.php**

*Notice the folder name Admin must be captital 'A'*

```
<?php

class Admin_HomeController extends Controller {
    public function showIndex() {
        return 'Yes it works!';
    }   
}
```

Alternatively you can use the group method

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin_HomeController@showIndex');
});
```

Thanks
Daniel