# Route to controller in subfolder not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, controller, routes, laravel, laravel-4

I was updating my Laravel 3 app to Laravel 4 when I hit this problem...

Routes I have tried:

```
Route::get('backend/login', 'backend/UserController@login');
Route::get('backend/login', 'backend.UserController@login');
```

Comment: have you updated your autoload file?  (composer dump-autoload)

Comment: Yes, autoload file has been updated but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you just get a 404 or do you get a more useful error?  If you get an error, can you please post it here?

Comment: Also, is your controller in a namespace?

Comment: No, the controller is not in a namespace.

Comment: The error I get is ReflectionException: Class backend/UserController does not exist

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I think you can just do Route::get('backend/login', 'UserController@login'); Once your controllers been registered Laravel just knows where it is.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue just a few hours ago and had to play a little bit with it to have it working.

Routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::resource('/', 'admin\DashboardController');
});
```

In "controllers/admin" i put the DashboardController:

```
namespace admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class DashboardController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }

}
```

That did the trick on Laravel 4. Hope you find it useful enough. :)

Comment: It's very helpful. You save the day.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, in Laravel 4 Beta 1, you can "only ?" use namespace.

For exemple here in your controller file: app/controllers/backend/UserController.php

```
<?php namespace Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {

    // Note extends Controller and not BaseController

    // Your stuff
}
?>
```

So after, in file: app/routes.php :

```
<?php
Route::get('backend/login', 'Controllers\Backend\UserController@login');
```

I don't know if is the better way, but working here. Edit & dump-autoload "composer.json" seems not work actualy.

If someone can improve that, he will make my day ! :)

Comment: Still not working:

Route: Route::get('backend/login', 'Controllers\Backend\UserController@login');

Class (in app/controllers/backend/UserController.php): <?php namespace Controllers\Backend;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends BaseController 
{

Error: ReflectionException: Class Controllers\Backend\UserController does not exist

Comment: ok, as i say, take care of : 
'"class UserController extends Controller"' 
not
'"class UserController extends BaseController"'

Comment: hum, the sample code a give you work here :/. Don't forget to run "composer dump-autoload" after any add/remove controllers : [Docs/Controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers)

Comment: glad to help you, have fun w/ laravel now :)

Comment: Ok "composer dump-autoload" did the trick but now I get the following error: FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Controllers\Backend\View' not found on this line of code: return View::make('backend.user.login');

Comment: Hum, it look like classic package development... I can't test it anymore today, but go reading [jason lewis](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench) blog for more infos.
You can try to include: `use Illuminate\View\Environment;` in your controller and set up the __construct() function

Comment: @CliffordJames - That error is being thrown because your View is in a different namespace than your Controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are gonna use Laravel 4, perhaps you should take a look of this: You can specify the namespace to be used on a group of routes, as you can see here: http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/route-group-namespacing

So in your sample:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend', 'namespace' => 'backend'), function()
{

    Route::get('login', 'UserController@login');

});
```

It works like a charm :)

I've been using it, and are quite good, it helps you keep your code cleaner and more understandable. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'backend'), function() {
    // Responds to Request::root() . '/backend/user'
    Route::resource('login', 'UserController');
});
```

see more info here

[Laravel 4 nested resource controllers Route::resource('admin/photo', 'PhotoController'); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585654/laravel-4-nested-resource-controllers-routeresourceadmin-photo-photocontr)

Answer (score 0):

My Admin Controller in app/controllers  directory

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {
/**.
 * @return \AdminController
 */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

Now I have a folder named admin in controllers folder i.e   app/controllers/admin and I have another controller there named AdminDashboardController.php

```
class AdminDashboardController extends AdminController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function getIndex()
    {
    return View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }
    }
```

And Lastly My Route.php file

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
 });
```

Hope this helps ..:-)

Answer (score 0):

As explained here, with Laravel 4.1 you can specify the namespace to be used on a group of routes, as you can see here: http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/route-group-namespacing

I've been using it, and are quite good, it helps you keep your code cleaner and more understandable. Give it a try!

Answer (score -1):

You could also put your backend/admin panel in a package..fruit for thought :)