# Laravel 4 - changing resource root routing path

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, uri

In a Laravel 4 installation, Using [Jeffrey Way's Laravel 4 Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#resources), I set up a 'tweet' resource, using the scaffolding command from his example:

```
php artisan generate:scaffold tweet --fields="author:string, body:text"
```

This generated the model, view, controller, migration and routing information for the tweet type. After migrating the database, visiting `http://localhost:8000/tweets` works fine, and shows the expected content.

The contents of the `routes.php` file at this point is:

```
Route::resource('tweets', 'TweetsController');
```

---

Now I would like to move the url for `tweets` up one level into `admin/tweets`, so the above url should become: `http://localhost:8000/admin/tweets`. Please note that I am not treating 'Admin' as a resource, but instead just want to add it for hypothetical organizational purposes.

Changing the routes.php file to:

```
Route::resource('admin/tweets', 'TweetsController');
```

Does not work, and displays the following error:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "tweets.create" as such route does not exist.

Similarly when using the following:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    Route::resource('tweets', 'TweetsController');
});
```

As was suggested in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585654/laravel-4-nested-resource-controllers-routeresourceadmin-photo-photocontr).

Using `php artisan routes` reveals that the named routes also now have `admin` prefixed to them, turning `tweets.create` into `admin.tweets.create`.

---

Why is the error saying that it cannot find `tweets.create`? shouldn't that automatically be resolved (judging by the routes table), to use `admin.tweets.create`?

How can I change my routing so that this error no longer occurs?

Comment: I just tested with new resource controller and it works fine for me.The problem is not with the Route, its with the view files check your view files there are link to route like `link_to_route('tweets.create', 'Add new tweet')`, this is creating the error because when you add `admin` as prefix `tweets.create` doesnot exists so change it to `admin.tweets.create` every where, in your controller also where ever named route is used

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I actually just noticed this myself. Should have looked a bit longer before posting a question :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested with new resource controller and it works fine for me.
The problem is not with the Route, its with the `named routes` used in your application.

check your view files there are link to route like `link_to_route('tweets.create', 'Add new tweet')`, this is creating the error because when you add `admin` as prefix `tweets.create` doesn't exists so change it to `admin.tweets.create` every where, in your `controller` also where ever named route is used.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a better way of linking routes in views that wouldn't break if you add a prefix like this? Probably using link_to_action?

Comment: yes best bet `link_to_action('TweetsController@create', 'Add new tweet')`